# How to use a second retriever in LangChain to get extra info?

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

In the following LangChain code, how can I add a second retriever to get extra info when the information is not found in the first documents?

```py
# Build prompt
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer. Use three sentences maximum. Keep the answer as concise as possible. Always say "thanks for asking!" at the end of the answer. 
{context}
Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""
QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context", "question"],template=template,)

# Run chain
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
question = "Is probability a class topic?"
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm,
                                       retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
                                       return_source_documents=True,
                                       chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT})


result = qa_chain({"query": question})
result["result"]
```

What I want is to change the prompt and use a second retriever (created with a different set of documents than the first one).

Something like:

```py
#...similar code...different prompt
template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, try to look at the extra text, and if still impossible to find a good answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer. Use three sentences maximum. Keep the answer as concise as possible. Always say "thanks for asking!" at the end of the answer. 
{context}
Extra: {extra_information}
Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""
QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context", "extra", "question"],template=template,)
#...similar code...

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm,
                                       retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
                                       extra_retriever=extradb.as_retriever(), #I know this parameter don't exist
                                       return_source_documents=True,
                                       chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT})
```

What is the correct way to use a second set of documents in LangChain?